# Ortools GLOP - Removal of redundant constraints cause double the run time

Tags: or-tools

I'm trying to solve a linear problem with about 5,000 variables, and 10,000 constraints. In some cases, a few of the constraints are redundant. When I tried to remove those constraints, the run time of the solver was doubled. I'm confused about why this is happening...

I've exported the two models, and verified that they are identical (beside the redundant constraints), and that those constraints are indeed redundant.
Any idea why this is happening?

Version: 9.1.9490
Language: Java
solver: GLOP
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3

Comment: Please indicate when you are crossposting.

Comment: What do you mean by redundant ? Exact duplicates ? logically implied ?

Comment: Exact duplicate.                                                                                                            A simplified example: I have something like:                                                                  a*x + b*y <= value, a*x + c*y <= value.                                                                       
In some cases, I have b=c, so the second constraint is redundant.

Comment: no, adding b = c is a very strong simplification. It is not a redundant constraint. It makes some of the other constraints of the model redundant. This is not the same.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough... b=c is not another constraint, they are constants coming from some other part of the program.

Comment: So we are going to the post I removed, one explanation is that it changes the order of constraints in the model, and all LP and especially MIP solvers are very sensitive to the order of constraints and variables.

Comment: One thing bothers me. Are you comparing apple vs apple ? Are you comparing exactly one model vs one model with redundant constraints, or different models, one where b = c, and one where b != c ?

Comment: Sorry, just now saw your reply... The models compared were both with b=c. The only difference was the added redundant constraints. The order of constraints was the only explanation made sense to me... Thanks!